# Treeview save/load to xml too slow

Tags: xml, delphi, treeview

At the moment there are some 40,000 nodes in the treeview which is the standard TTreeView of XE6.
The problem is that save/load takes long time (about 2 minutes) and the number of nodes is expected to grow in the future.

What is your opinion on improving the speed? Any other way of save/load besides xml? Any other treeview component?

Edit: Ok, the whole truth and nothing but truth. I just measured (using no fancy instrumentation, just one Mississippi, two Mississippi, ...)  the load/save time. Save is about 5 seconds and load is a bit less than 5 seconds. It just feels so sluggish and unresponsive that I had the impression that it took 2 minutes. :)
Thanks

Code:

```
procedure TTree.Save(aTreeView: TTreeView; aFilePath: String);
var
  oTreeNode: TTreeNode;
  oXMLDocument: IXMLDocument;
  oXMLNode: IXMLNode;
  procedure ProcessTreeItem(aTreeNode: TTreeNode; aXMLNode: IXMLNode);
  var
    oTemp: IXMLNode;
  begin
    if (aTreeNode = nil) then Exit;
    oTemp := aXMLNode.AddChild('item');
    oTemp.Attributes['text'] := aTreeNode.Text;
    oTemp.Attributes['NodeID'] := TNode(aTreeNode.Data).ID;
    oTemp.Attributes['NodeType'] := TNode(aTreeNode.Data).NodeType;
    oTemp.Attributes['Selected'] := aTreeNode.Selected;
    aTreeNode := aTreeNode.getFirstChild;
    while aTreeNode <> nil do begin
      ProcessTreeItem(aTreeNode, oTemp);
      aTreeNode := aTreeNode.getNextSibling;
    end;
  end;
begin
  oXMLDocument := NewXMLDocument;
  oXMLDocument.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent];
  oXMLNode := oXMLDocument.AddChild('xml');
  oTreeNode := aTreeView.TopItem;
  while oTreeNode <> nil do begin
    ProcessTreeItem(oTreeNode, oXMLNode);
    oTreeNode := oTreeNode.getNextSibling;
  end;
  oXMLDocument.SaveToFile(aFilePath);
end;
procedure TTree.Load(aTreeView: TTreeView; aFilePath: String);
var
  oXMLNode: IXMLNode;
  oXMLDocument: IXMLDocument;
  procedure ProcessNode(aXMLNode: IXMLNode; aTreeNode: TTreeNode);
  var
    bExpanded: Boolean;
    oNodeData: TNode;
    oTemp: IXMLNode;
  begin
    if aXMLNode = nil then Exit;
    oNodeData := CreateNode(Integer(aXMLNode.Attributes['NodeID']), aXMLNode.Attributes['NodeType']);
    aTreeNode := aTreeView.Items.AddChildObject(aTreeNode, aXMLNode.Attributes['text'], oNodeData);
    aTreeNode.Selected := aXMLNode.Attributes['Selected'];
    oTemp := aXMLNode.ChildNodes.First;
    while oTemp <> nil do begin
      ProcessNode(oTemp, aTreeNode);
      oTemp := oTemp.NextSibling;
    end;
  end;
begin
  aTreeView.Items.Clear;
  oXMLDocument := NewXMLDocument;
  oXMLDocument.LoadFromFile(aFilePath);
  oXMLNode := oXMLDocument.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.First;
  while oXMLNode <> nil do begin
    ProcessNode(oXMLNode, nil);
    oXMLNode := oXMLNode.NextSibling;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

When looking at your code I miss a BeginUpdate / EndUpdate. That can greatly improve speed.

```
aTreeView.Items.BeginUpdate;
try
  // clear and add your items here

finally
  aTreeView.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for comment Sebastian. I have those when calling the Load procedure. I guess the effect is the same?

Comment: If you call BeginUpdate before you call the Load procedure then that is good enough. But I can only comment on the code I see. BTW: Adding 40000 items to a VCL TTreeView takes 2 seconds on my PC.

Comment: Is that a real application or you just made a test app?

Comment: This isn't it. If adding 40000 nodes takes 2 seconds, there's nothing more to say.

Comment: @Mike Isn't a test app exactly what is needed to explore this?

Comment: Sure. Just wanted to exchange a bit of other issues with Sebastian if it's a real app, for example which xml library he uses, etc.

Comment: I created a test application in order to measure how long it takes to fill a TTreeView with 40000 items. If you need a faster treeview, use Virtual TreeView.

Comment: David, I don't know if you can delete this thread but please do so if you can as I doubt that this question with the current responses would be useful for anybody.

Comment: You could delete it if you did not have upvoted answers. We can close and delete if there are enough votes. 5 close and then 3 delete.